# How to encourage comments to be polite and at an academic level?

Tags: discussion, scope, comments

**How to encourage comments to be polite and at an academic level?**

Lately I have noticed that comments are at times a low quality within themselves, on both main and meta sites. Some are somewhat not polite. I am not going to bring up examples here, but would like to know how do we encourage others to remain respectable, yet **academic in their comments**?

Some of these commentators have been around long enough to know how the site works.

It could be pointed out that some of these comments are not just limited to the comment boxes, but can be found within questions and/or answers.

Working as a community we can strengthen the site. Pickering will simply get us lost in translation and individuals will eventually get discouraged and possibly leave.

Let us be as professional as possible!

> **Comments on questions…**
>
> - May ask for clarification about what is being asked or the scope of the question.
> - Should help the OP along the road to a clear question that will elicit the answer they are looking for.
> - Should not answer the question. Don’t. Just don’t. If you know the answer to the question, post it as an answer.
> - Should not dish out spiritual advice. See: [But can't I just say one thing?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing)
> - May link to other resources such as related questions on the site but may not link to things expected to substitute for an answer the question.
>
> **Comments on answers…**
>
> - May ask for clarification about how a point answers the question if it isn’t clear.
> - May ask the answer to further explain some aspect of the question not originally addressed.
> - May correct factual details that can be reasonably corrected by the author without changing the substance of the answer.
> - May inform the author that they missed something about the scope of a question (or that a question was edited) that they should take into account in their post.
> - Should not provide alternatives to a completely wrong answer. If an answer is just wrong and you feel the need to set the record straight, vote it down and then hit up that answer form and submit a better entry.
> - Should not explain how the beliefs described in an aswer are wrong theologically. If they wrongly represent the theological tradition asked about in the scope of the question that’s one thing, but if they are just flat out wrong then stay away from that comment link.
>
> [**When is a comment not a comment?**](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/when-is-a-comment-not-a-comment)

Comment: It doesn’t seem like something you can engineer - what I think is required is leadership by example. That’s something we should expect from community members who have been around for a while.

Comment: On other SE sites (I am thinking of one in particular) temporary bans are immediately imposed when users make impolite comments. Repeated bad behaviour results in a total ban.

Comment: @NigelJ Something to think about, but I would rather not.

Comment: I agree. We are in a (hopefully) academic setting and sometimes that becomes robust. But it should never descend into personal impoliteness. If that is respected there need be no sanctions.

Comment: No one is paid to make questions, answers, or comments on C SE. It's not a professional site. Most people who post here aren't academics. I'm not really convinced that should even be the target, as academics have both strengths and weaknesses (in the latter category, being afraid to say the truth if it will rock their institutional boat, among other things).