# Why are people down-voting legitimate question without explanation?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Christianity Stack Exchange post: [Were the ancient Israelites of a darker skin tone?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/were-the-ancient-israelites-of-a-darker-skin-tone/62567#62567)

Why are you censoring my answer?

What is your disagreement?

How am I supposed to address or change anything if I get downvoted without a comment?

To me it seems like fascism and censorship of different views.

Is this forum for certain denomination of Christians only or are all welcome?

Answer (score 5):

[Voting is anonymous](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1393/21576) on purpose, and thus we don't badger downvoters who don't wish to comment.

That said, you did receive feedback – there is a message on the bottom of your post that you should read.  This site is for all self-identifying Christian denominations, but personal opinion is not on-topic.  Telling us how you know something is at least as important as telling us what you know.

If you'd like further explanation, I'd recommend reviewing the help pages, particularly [How to Answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  You can also ask for advice here on meta, as you do here, but throwing around nonsensical accusations of censorship and fascism will not do you any favors.  Besides the fact that your post has not (yet) been deleted, this is a private site, and you do not have an inalienable right to post here.  If you violate our guidelines, your content will not be kept.

But if you want to learn how we operate, and adjust your questions and answers accordingly, then you are welcome, regardless of your religion or denomination.

Comment: thanks for reply I will update my answer, but how do you expect any new comers? To me it seems you suffer of some form of biased elitism that most of stack exchange forums also suffer from...

Comment: @ChenChi We believe that our guidelines, being more strict than might be found on discussion forums and other Q&A sites, result in higher-quality content.  That may mean fewer contributors, but our niche is quality, not quantity.

Comment: Well in the post that I tried to answer I didn't find any good quality answers... very poor and narrow information was featured in the answers.

Comment: @ChenChi Agreed.  We'd definitely like to see better answers to that question, and even the question itself (as indicated by its score) isn't one of our best.

Comment: `but how do you expect any new comers? To me it seems you suffer of some form of biased elitism that most of stack exchange forums also suffer from...`   It's not elitism to  expect and require that newcomers will put in a _small_ effort to understand how the site works.  It's expected that a newcomer will read a few posts or look at a few guidelines and  help pages before posting.  It's extremely selfish for a newcomer to join a new site, start posting anything they want, and then say, "you're fascist and elitist and censoring me because you won't tell me exactly what I want!"

Comment: *To me it seems you suffer of some form of biased elitism that most of stack exchange forums also suffer from* (1) SE are explicitly **not** forums.   That is on purpose.  (2) Having higher standards than the rest of the internet is an explicit goal of SE as a system.  The whole point of the SE model is to get a better-than-the- mean signal to noise ratio.   If that is what you call elitism, then please join the elite. (No, we don't have a secret handshake, but if you participate enough you'll get some cool badges next to your name. :)  )

Answer (score 1):

#### *Is this forum for certain denomination of Christians only or are all welcome*?

I want to spell out clearly the answer to this part of your question.

1. All Christians are welcome, regardless of their faith community.
2. Non Christians are also welcome.

The only requirement is to participate within the boundaries already established for the SE model, and the community's agreed ways to avoid the kind of noise and bickering that is all-too-common on the rest of the internet.  Since the original beta version of this SE, which was back in 2010 or so, it has taken a while to figure out, collectively, how to achieve those objectives while addressing this potentially explosive topic: Christianity.

Lastly, it is SE-wide policy that a comment is not required when casting a down vote, and I often find that as frustrating as you do.  I usually provide a comment if my down vote is linked to how the question is unclear, or I have a particular suggestion on how to improve the question. (Likewise with answers).  But there is no requirement to do so.

I am now going to something a little silly, [and quote myself](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/does-this-site-have-a-novel-approach-to-christianity/6359#6359):

> Because this community is not interested (collectively) in the great, 1900-year-long shouting match of "I'm right, you splitter!" -- "No, I'm right, you heretic!" this is a unique internet space where I can engage warmly with my fellow believers from across the denominational spectrum.

And I'd hope it stays that way.